# Share folder and drive on home network. Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, xubuntu, file-sharing

I wish to share files and folders in my home network to use it on Kodi on other devices in network. I am using Xbubuntu 18.04 64bit. I can easily do the same with windows 10 os but I prefer we all prefer linux over windows. I am noob here please do share a detailed tutorial. Thank you for your good work.